# How are Linux shells and filesystem Unicode-aware?

Tags: linux, shell, unicode, utf-8

I understand that Linux filesystem stores file names as byte sequences which is meant to be Unicode-encoding-independent.

But, encodings other than UTF-8 or Enhanced UTF-8 may very well use 0 byte as part of a multibyte representation of a Unicode character that can appear in a file name.  And everywhere in Linux filesystem C code you terminate strings with 0 byte. So how does Linux filesystem support Unicode?  Does it assume all applications that create filenames use UTF-8 only?  But that is not true, is it?

Similarly, the shells (such as bash) use `*` in patterns to match any number of filename characters.  I can see in shell C code that it simply uses the ASCII byte for `*` and goes byte-by-byte to delimit the match.  Fine for UTF-8 encoded names, because it has the property that if you take the byte representation of a string, then match some bytes from the start with `*`, and match the rest with another string, then the bytes at the beginning in fact matched a string of whole characters, not just bytes.

But other encodings do not have that property, do they?  So again, do shells assume UTF-8?

Comment: Neither I nor Google has heard of "Enhanced UTF-8", what is it?

Comment: @zwol Oops sorry, should be "modified UTF-8".

Comment: ... I don't know what that would be, either?

Comment: @zwol modified UTF-8 differs from UTF-8 in how the null character is encoded  - in modified, it is not the zero byte, but a specific two-byte sequence, this way, you can have zero-byte terminated strings of characters.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8

Comment: If you only really want to ask about filename compatibility, maybe tweak the question title?  By the title, this seems to be also asking about the shell's string representation, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no encoding of filenames in Linux (in ext family of filesystems at any rate). Filenames are sequences of bytes, not characters. It is up to application programs to interpret these bytes as UTF-8 or anything else. The filesystem doesn't care.

POSIX stipulates that the shell [obeys the locale environment vsriables such as LC_CTYPE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) when performing pattern matches. Thus, pattern-matching code that just compares bytes regardless of the encoding would not be compatible with your hypothetical encoding, or with any stateful encoding. But this doesn't seem to matter much as such encodings are not commonly supported by existing locales. UTF-8 on the other hand seems to be supported well: in my experiments `bash` correctly matches the `?` character with a single Unicode character, rather than a single byte, in the filename (given an UTF-8 locale) as prescribed by POSIX.

Comment: Might want to mention that byte values 0x00 and 0x2F (and no others) are significant to the kernel in pathnames, and cannot appear in a pathname _component_.

Comment: @n.m. the fragment "would not be compatible with your hypothetical...not commonly supported by existing locales"  this is my answer, right there, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

It is true that UTF-16 and other "wide character" encodings cannot be used for pathnames in Linux (nor any other POSIX-compliant OS).

It is *not* true in principle that anyone assumes UTF-8, although that may come to be true in the future as other encodings die off.  What Unix-style programs assume is an *ASCII-compatible* encoding.  Any encoding with these properties is ASCII-compatible:

- The fundamental unit of the encoding is a byte, not a larger entity.  Some characters might be encoded as a *sequence* of bytes, but there must be at least 127 characters that are encoded using only a single byte, namely:
- The characters defined by ASCII (nowadays, these are best described as Unicode codepoints U+000000 through U+00007F, inclusive) are encoded as single bytes, with values equal to their Unicode codepoints.
- Conversely, the bytes with values 0x00 through 0x7F must always *decode* to the characters defined by ASCII, regardless of surrounding context.  (For instance, the string 0x81 0x2F must decode to two characters, whatever 0x81 decodes to and then `/`.)

UTF-8 is ASCII-compatible, but so are all of the ISO-8859-n pages, the [EUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Unix_Code) encodings, and many, many others.

Some programs may also require an additional property:

- The encoding of a character, viewed as a sequence of bytes, is never a proper prefix nor a proper suffix of the encoding of any other character.

UTF-8 has this property, but (I think) EUC-JP doesn't.

It is *also* the case that many "Unix-style" programs reserve the codepoint U+000000 (NUL) for use as a string terminator.  This is technically *not* a constraint on the *encoding*, but on the text itself.  (The closely-related requirement that the *byte* 0x00 not appear in the middle of a string is a consequence of this plus the requirement that 0x00 maps to U+000000 regardless of surrounding context.)

Comment: well...  so then, let's consider dash, a POSIX-compatible shell, when its C code tries to do filename expansion of a pattern containing `*`.  Suppose that we have an encoding with two non-ascii characters encoded as 0x81 and 0x80 0x81.  According to your definition, such an encoding may well be ASCII-compatible, so dash should work.  But it seems to me, that it does not.  The pattern `<whatever 0x81 decodes to>*<whatever 0x81 decodes to>` will match the file name `<whatever 0x81 decodes to><whatever 0x80 0x81 decodes to>`, which is wrong.

Comment: I don't think Unicode codepoints have "hex digits". They're just numbers. So you could just say, "with values equal to their Unicode codepoint".

Comment: @MarkGaleck It may well be that dash's glob algorithm is buggy in the face of some multi-byte ASCII-compatible encodings that are not UTF-8; that would be a case of my "that may come to be true in the future" already having happened.  (UTF-8 has the additional property that no valid character encoding is a proper prefix or proper suffix of another valid character encoding, which prevents your hypothetical from happening.  I *think* that it could happen in EUC-JP, but that's going from the somewhat unclear description on Wikipedia; I haven't been able to construct a file that trips it.)

Comment: @zwol  thank you I upvoted your answer but I accepted the other one.  I don't really understand your wording "some programs may also require...", are you saying the shells require that? Where is that documented?  And the additional property you state, is still not sufficient IMHO - I already wrote the correct property myself in the question.

Comment: @MarkGaleck "No character's encoding is a proper prefix or suffix of another character's encoding" implies "if you take the byte representation of a string, then match some bytes from the start with *, and match the rest with another string, then the bytes at the beginning in fact matched a string of whole characters, not just bytes."  Because the "rest" cannot begin to match except at a character boundary, and character boundaries are unambiguous.